# Hiding the last item in case of overflow via CSS

Tags: css, overflow

I have a `.list` of `.item`s, like this one:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

Both `.item` and `.list` have a **maximal** height, say 100px and 280px.
I'd like to hide the last `.item` when it overflows, possibly with no JS.

What I mean is that if `.list` has `overflow: hidden`, and all `.item`s reach the max height, then the last one is partially cut. I'd like to hide it completely, i.e. either it fits, or it disappears.

I can change both the CSS and the HTML (including, e.g., using `<ul><li>...` instead of `div`s)

Comment: You're going to need JS to measure the height of all the items and see if that exceeds the height of the list.

Comment: And resizing the `.list` to 300px is not an option?

Comment: This cannot simply be achieved using CSS

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody... I'm in fact using js, although I'd like a more clean solution :/

Comment: @ecesena lease post your solution and accept, I'd like to see how you did it.

Answer (score 2):

If your items would've had a fixed height, and not a maximum, you could've used nth-child to predict at which item it will start to overflow.

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/p2CF9/) | Code

```
.item{
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

.item:nth-child(1n+4){ /* 4th element and up */
    display: none;
}

.list{
    max-height: 280px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, since they aren't fixed heights, the only solution for such dynamics is using javascript.

---

On that note, here's a javascript solution.

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/p2CF9/2/) | Code

Javascript

```
var eList = document.getElementById("list"),
    eItems = eList.getElementsByTagName("div"),
    iMaxHeight = parseInt(getStyle(eList, "max-height")),
    iSumHeight = 0;

for(i = 0; i < eItems.length; i++){
    var iHeight = parseInt(getStyle(eItems[i], "height"));
    //Check if next item will overflow, in which case, we're going to hide it
    if((iSumHeight + iHeight) >= iMaxHeight){
        eItems[i].style.display = "none";
    }else{
        iSumHeight += iHeight;
    }
}

function getStyle(el,styleProp){
    if (el.currentStyle)
        var y = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac. Nam venenatis, nunc sit amet elementum semper, sem purus ultrices diam, quis scelerisque elit nulla sed sapien. Vivamus urna metus, tincidunt ac accumsan et, dignissim at lorem.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac. Nam venenatis, nunc sit amet elementum semper, sem purus ultrices diam, quis scelerisque elit nulla sed sapien. Vivamus urna metus, tincidunt ac accumsan et, dignissim at lorem.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac. Nam venenatis, nunc sit amet elementum semper, sem purus ultrices diam, quis scelerisque elit nulla sed sapien. Vivamus urna metus, tincidunt ac accumsan et, dignissim at lorem.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac. Nam venenatis, nunc sit amet elementum semper, sem purus ultrices diam, quis scelerisque elit nulla sed sapien. Vivamus urna metus, tincidunt ac accumsan et, dignissim at lorem.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac. Nam venenatis, nunc sit amet elementum semper, sem purus ultrices diam, quis scelerisque elit nulla sed sapien. Vivamus urna metus, tincidunt ac accumsan et, dignissim at lorem.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac. Nam venenatis, nunc sit amet elementum semper, sem purus ultrices diam, quis scelerisque elit nulla sed sapien. Vivamus urna metus, tincidunt ac accumsan et, dignissim at lorem.</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pulvinar aliquet risus, vitae suscipit tortor cursus ac.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item{
    max-height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#list{
    max-height: 290px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I render the page dynamically, so if I'd know the exact height I could actually avoid the problem... unfortunately the height depends upon the content :( But thanks anyway, the use of nth-child is of independent interest!

Comment: @ecesena I updated the post with a javascript solution. In any case, you won't find an answer to your question that is not javascript based, because CSS alone simply can't do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to compute height of items, or if you want to do it just with css and you know that heights of both elements will not change, you can compute how many will fit and hide others using nth-child css selector [nth-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)